# Stimulsoft report.js report in react native

Tags: react-native, stimulsoft

I am a beginner in React native.

How can i use stimulsoft report.js to work with react native.

Here is the sample for normal React
Can this use in React Native.
Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Report.mrt</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/stimulsoft.reports.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/stimulsoft.reports.maps.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>

        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/babel">
            class Export extends React.Component {
                render() {
                    return <div id="exportContent"></div>;
                }

                componentWillMount() {
                    var report = Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.createNewReport();
                    report.loadFile("reports/Report.mrt");

                    report.renderAsync(function () {
                        var data = report.exportDocument(Stimulsoft.Report.StiExportFormat.Pdf);
                        Object.saveAs(data, "Report.pdf", "application/pdf");
                    })
                }
            }

            ReactDOM.render(
                <Export />,
                document.getElementById("main")
            )
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code snippet ?

Comment: code snippet is for react not for react native

Answer (score 1):

Basically **you cannot**. HTML based components won't compile to native ones.

What you can do is to try to **use WebView** in your mobile app.